# Помогите с формой на php

Tags: php

помогите, сделал простую форму обратной связи,с отправкой данных на почту ( можно сказать в первые).
И вот когда я ввожу в форме данные а именно почта и телефон срабатывает метод else

Вот сайт - http://cu22636.tmweb.ru/

Код :

```
<?php

    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $tel = htmlspecialchars[$tel];
    $email = htmlspecialchars[$email];

    $tel = urldecode[$tel];
    $email = urldecode[$email];

    $tel = trim[$tel];
    $email = trim[$email];

    if(mail("tellsyt3@gmail.com",
        "Новое писмо с сайта",
        "Телефон: ".$tel. "\n".
         "Почта: ".$email. "\n",
         "From: no-perly@mydomain.ru")
    ){
         echo ("Ждите звонка");
    }

    else {
        echo("Не");
    
    }
?>
```

Comment: Может стоит все-же приложить код?

Comment: Такие вопросы следует писать не Спортлото, а в службу поддержки хостинга.

Comment: уберите if else и посмотрите ошибку, возможно на вашем хостинге не поддерживается функция mail, посмотрите в сторону send_mail

Comment: При использовании ф-ций `htmlspecialchars()`, `urldecode()`, `trim()` замените квадратные скобки на круглые.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте указать SMTP и адрес отправителя почты:

```
<?php

ini_set("SMTP", "aspmx.l.google.com");
ini_set("sendmail_from", "tellsyt3@gmail.com");

$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$tel = htmlspecialchars($tel);
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);

$tel = urldecode($tel);
$email = urldecode($email);

$tel = trim($tel);
$email = trim($email);

$result = mail("tellsyt3@gmail.com",
        "Новое писмо с сайта",
        "Телефон: " . $tel . "\n" .
        "Почта: " . $email . "\n",
        "From: tellsyt3@gmail.com");
if ($result) {
    echo ("Ждите звонка");
} else {
    echo("Не");
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Для функций `htmlspecialchars()`, `urldecode()`, `trim()` замените квадратные скобки на круглые.

Comment: Simon, упс, поправил

Comment: Я извиняюсь, А ЧЕМ это поможет?!